# Use of coroutines in an android library affects Java application

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am creating an android library (in kotlin) in which I will do some blocking IO operations. I would like to use kotlin coroutines to accomplish this, as described here: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines#use-coroutines-for-main-safety

If my library is included as a dependency in an android application written in Java, in what way does the use of coroutines affect that application project.

Note: I am not looking for a performance comparison, but rather in the perspective of project setup, required dependencies, required versions, etc.

Comment: I don't see any threat that anything is going to be affected. A non-suspend function is easily callable from inside a coroutine (just make sure the code which requires blocking IO is dispatched in proper thread), project setup is the same way, just add dependency to the kotlinx-coroutines-core.